# Decompressed gziped file disappears?

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, gzip, ls

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running CentOs. Unfortunately I don't have a gui. I tried setting up x11 forwarding but apparently it works differently with Ubuntu than it does with CentOs. But thats not the point. I download a pretty large .gz file (8.7Gb) and extracted using the following command:

```
gzip -d [filename] &
```

it took nearly an hour to decompress, and using `ls -l` I could see that the uncompressed directory was going to be nearly 30 gb. Anyway the process finishes and when I `ls` again the directory is no where to be found. I tried `ls -a` as well but still nothing. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like gzip is silently failing when it runs out of space. How large is your instance's EBS volume / local disk that you're unzipping onto? (run `df -h` and figure out which device you're unzipping in.)

Additionally you could try to run gzip in verbose mode to catch any errors it might not be showing. I don't have a CentOS machine handy, but you might be able to use `gzip -l [filename]` to figure out whether your file is too big for the target directory.

Comment: That's apparently what's happening, the ebs volume has about 40 Gb free and apparently the uncompressed file is about 70.